# Fazer com que cada botão, durante o evento onclik, faça despoletar a sua própria janela?

Tags: php, javascript

O seguinte código irá apresentar vários "tumbnails", onde cada um tem um botão designado de "tracklist". Mas acontece, por exemplo, se eu clicar num dos botões e se não fechar a respetiva  janela, todos os outros botões "tracklist" que forem "clicados" ou ativados irão "escrever" na primeira janela aberta...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(content) {
    var playlist = content;    
    var x = parseInt((screen.width-800)/2);
    var y = parseInt((screen.height-600)/2);
    var win = window.open( '', 'pop', 'scrollbars=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600' ); 
    win.document.write ('Playlist:' + playlist); 
    win.moveTo(x,y);
}
</script>
</head>
```

PHP

```
foreach($rows as $row){
   echo "<div class='tumbnail'>";
   echo "<img src='imagem.jpg'>";
   echo "<input class=\"btn_tracklist\" type=\"button\" value=\"Tracklist\" onclick=\"javascript:myFunction('" . $row['tracklist'] . "')\"> </br>";                                
   echo "</div>";
 } /*END Foreach*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique o javascript.
Ao invés de :

```
var win = window.open( '', 'pop', 'scrollbars=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600' );
```

use

```
var win = window.open( '', '_blank', 'scrollbars=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=800,height=600' );
```

ou defina um nome diferente para cada janela

Veja o parametro name do window open: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp